# Postgresql JPA incrementing field

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa

I have application using JPA and Postgresql. I have exisiting database, and I need to add a field to exsiting table, which should be auto incremented. I need to provide that values for new record will be always greater than the previous record. Also I need to add values for the record that exists...

I've thought that id field will suite my requirements, but it doesn't... I have a primary key which is generated by sequence in PostgreSQL, but values aren't always greater. Application is used by many concurrent clients.

Comment: Your saying that sequnce in PostgreSQL isn't returning valueas which aren't always greater then previous? Or what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL will create a sequence, alter the table and use the sequence to generate and set the default value in the new column:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE myid_seq;
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN myid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('myid_seq');
```

So the number will be set by the database when a new row is inserted. (i.e. no problem if you have many concurrent insert). 
Existing rows will be updated with a unique value for `myid`.

You can add a unicity constraint if you need it.